# Existence a subset of $\Bbb R$ such that $A\cap A^\prime=\emptyset$ with $\overline{A}$ uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there a subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $A\cap A^\prime=\emptyset$ and  $\overline{A}$ uncountable?

**My Attempt:**

$$A\cap A^\prime=\emptyset\quad \Rightarrow \quad \overline{A}=A\cup A'=(A\cap A^\prime)\cup A=A$$
so $A$ is closed and  $A'\subseteq A$ thus $A'=A\cap A^\prime=\emptyset$.

Comment: Does $A'$ mean complement of $A$

Comment: No, set of all limit points. limit point and we know $\overline{A}=A^\prime\cup A$

Comment: Do you know that every irrational number is a limit of some rational sequence?

Comment: @user160738: Do you know that every rational number is also a limit of some rational sequence?

Comment: @Onil: But any interior point of an interval is also a limit point of the interval.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ah yes sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A point in the set $A$ that is not its limit point must be its isolated point. The condition that $A\cap A'=\emptyset$ is equivalent to the statement that the set $A$ consists only of isolated points. Its closure $\overline{A}$ can be uncountable. You can find a counter-intuitive example in the entry ***isolated point*** on wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point